# Multisim - How to create a 2-pin red/green LED in one part

Tags: led, multisim, ultiboard

I would like to pass the output of an LT1413CN8 op-amp through a 2-pin red/green LED (looks white when off) and back to it's inverted input.

In Multisim, there is a red/green LED option but that is a 3-pin configuration.  If I drag and drop a green LED and red LED from the component menu, wire them up tail to head, and transfer the design to Ultiboard, 2 separate LEDs and their footprints appear (which is expected.)

Is there anyway to build a custom component made up of those 2 LEDs, but with only 2 pins and 1 footprint?

Or, is there a component that I am not seeing in the component menu that solves this issue?

Or, is there a recently-updated library with this part?  I am using Multisim 14.1

Thank you.

Comment: Red AND green or a bi-directional red OR green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 pin red/green is called common cathode.
A 2 pin with red OR green is a bidirectional LED e.g. [Kingbright WP937EGW](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP937EGW.pdf) 
Then there is an LED with both red and green in the same package e.g.   [Marktech Optoelectronics MT2030-HRG-A](http://marktechopto.com/pdf/products/datasheet/MT2030-HRG-A.pdf)

A red green in the same package has the same model as any other LED.

If looking for a bidirectional then search for "bidirectional LED".

Comment: Misunderstood, thanks for the info.  It's both red and green in the same package, similar to the Marktech one.  And I'll just add a regular 2-pin LED to my schematic.  Thanks again